# Avocent Cyclades Serial Switch Disable Telnet Login message

Tags: switch, serial

Whenever I open a telnet connection via PuTTy to a serial port on my Avocent switch, it will print something like the following message:

> Sharing connection with other user(s): 'NONE@525', 'NONE@546'
>   Type the hot key to suspend the connection:  CTRL Z

This is interfering with scripts i have reading Telnet output. I cant find the setting to disable this in the UI (logged in as admin).

What is the name of this Banner? its Different from the login banner as that is unchecked.

Comment: Just fix the script to account for the banner.

Comment: @womble If it is already removed on one switch then it surely can be removed on another. Hacking the script to "work around it" is not a good solution nor is it what I am looking for.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention a banner existing on one switch but not another.  What are the differences between those two switches, then?